# How do you set up speed dial on Polycom IP6000 phones?

Tags: voip, asterisk, telephony, polycom

Basically I would like speed dial on this so I can press 1 and it will dial 101 AND I can press 2 and it will dial 555-555-5555. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's explained in the [IP6000 manual](https://support.polycom.com/content/dam/polycom-support/products/voice/soundstation-ip-series/user/en/soundstation-ip-6000-user-guide-sip-3-1.pdf).  You're looking for pages 3-3 and 3-14.

Comment: Normally RTFM isn't a good answer but it is logical here. +1

Comment: If someone finds the answer please post it in an edit. This link is now broken.

Comment: @Nelu The IP6000 manual is now available here:  https://support.polycom.com/content/dam/polycom-support/products/voice/soundstation-ip-series/user/en/soundstation-ip-6000-user-guide-sip-3-1.pdf

Answer (score 3):

It's been a long time since I've fiddled with a Polycom, but once you find it's IP address, open it as a webpage in a browser, then guess at the admin username and password (might be admin:admin).
There's probably some kind of configs in there.

Or you could, y'know.. Ask Polycom Support.